# Java: Combinations without repetition

Tags: java, combinations

I have a list of cards called hand

```
Arraylist<Card> hand = new Arraylist<Card>();
hand.add(new Card("As"));
hand.add(new Card("9h"));
...
```

The maximum limit of cards in hand is five.
I need to get all the combinations in the hand by choosing every three of cards in hand without repetitions and the order is not important.

Example:

> ["Ac","10k","5c","7h","3h"]

Result:

> [Ac, 10k, 5c]
>
> [Ac, 10k, 7h]
>
> [Ac, 10k, 3h]
>
> [Ac, 5c, 7h]
>
> [Ac, 5c, 3h]
>
> [Ac, 7h, 3h]
>
> [10k, 5c, 7h]
>
> [10k, 5c, 3h]
>
> [10k, 7h, 3h]
>
> [5c, 7h, 3h]

Edit: I did find an answered question related to this.

[Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Here is one of the example in java and I tweak it a little bit

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Card[] arr = { new Card(16), new Card(4), new Card(22), new Card(16), new Card(11) };
    combinations(arr, 3, 0, new Card[3]);
}

static void combinations(Card[] arr, int len, int startPosition, Card[] result){
    if (len == 0){
        String str = "";
        for(Card card : result)
        {
            str += card.CardString() + ", ";
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        return;
    }       
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
        combinations(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried yet? Have you done your research, I have a gut feeling that this problem has been solved before... take a look at all the "Related" questions

Comment: You don't have 5 cards in the hand in your example...

Comment: I would recommend to take a pen and write down all the possible permutations while using the lists index instead of the cards name. Then you can figure out how to iterate over the lists indices.

Comment: Maybe yuou cand find some ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215593/combination-and-permutation-algorithms-recursive